# Time required for conducting wire to reach the steady state current

Tags: electricity, inductance

Referring to the the hydraulic analogy, a fluid will take a start up time to buildup the kinetic energy of flow after the initial application of pressure until it reaches the steady state flow.

Similarly, electrons would take some time to build up inductance and current until it reaches the steady state current after the initial application of voltage.

The analogy is further demonstrated by water hammer and voltage spikes if the flow or current is brought to a sudden stop.

The question is: how would the start up time of a conducting wire be calculated based on the area, length, and conductivity?

A numerical example involving a copper wire would be good.

Ps. I have made some calculations - checking their validity would be good. I couldn't find any good reading relating to that from a google search. Any good reading suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The analogy to the kinetic energy of the moving liquid, mv<sup>2</sup>/2, is the energy of the magnetic field associated with the electric current, LI<sup>2</sup>/2. Here, the analogy of the inertia of the liquid is the inductance of the circuit, L.

The start-up time, though, also depends on the friction. In the electrical circuit the analogy of the friction is the resistance, R, and the start-up is determined by the time constant τ=L/R. You can find how exactly the start-up time depends on the time constant from many good sources on the web, but it is approximately equals 5τ

So to calculate the start-up time of the current, you need to determine the inductance and resistance of the circuit, which will depend on the material and geometry of various circuit elements.

Comment: I think that in addition to any inductances, any capacitance C in a circuit will also influence the time to reach a steady state due to the RC time constant. Transmission line theory covers this entire subject.